# treemap for ascending ID

Tags: java, treemap, linkedhashmap

i have a program where i have to read data from excel file and store them in a database . I am using LinkedHashmap to read each cell as a string. My excel file contains the above data:

> ID NAME SALARY
>
> 5 christine 2349000
>
> 6 paulina 1000
>
> 7 laura 12587458
>
> 8 efi 34567
>
> 43 jim 45878

When i am running the program i have succefully get the result that i want. The problem that i have now is tha i want to store the data in my database by ascending ID.
How i will do this? I know that i have to use treeMap but how exactly?
The code below is for storing the data in the database. I am reading the data from the second row of the excel file.

```
private static LinkedHashMap[] parseExcelColumnData(List sheetData) {

        LinkedHashMap[] tousRows = new LinkedHashMap[sheetData.size() - 1];
        for (int rowCounter = 1; rowCounter < sheetData.size(); rowCounter++) {

            List list = (List) sheetData.get(rowCounter);

            LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> tableFields = new LinkedHashMap(list.size());
            String str;
            String[] tousFields = new String[list.size()];
            int i = 0;

            for (int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++) {
                Cell cell = (Cell) list.get(j);
                if (cell != null) {
                    if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
                        tableFields.put(String.valueOf(cell
                                .getNumericCellValue()), cell.getCellType());
                    } else if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
                        tableFields.put(cell.getStringCellValue(), cell
                                .getCellType());
                    } else if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN) {
                        tableFields.put(String.valueOf(cell
                                .getBooleanCellValue()), cell.getCellType());
                    }
                }

            }
            tousRows[rowCounter - 1] = tableFields;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Store your treemap keys (Ids) as integers, not as strings; otherwise they'll be compared in lexicographic order instead of in numeric order.

```
Integer intId = new Integer(stringId);
```

Now you just need to allocate a `TreeMap<Integer, Object>` (or `TreeMap<Integer, String>` or whatever depending on what it is you're storing) where the key is the integer ID and the value is the object to be stored.

```
TreeMap<Integer, Object> treeMap = new TreeMap<Integer, Object>();
treeMap.put(intId, obj);
```

When it comes time to read out the values, use `treeMap.values()` and you'll get a sorted collection of the values in the treemap.